# Mono.Cecil GetTypeReference to ICommand

Tags: .net, aop, mono.cecil, fody

The [System.Windows.Input.ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) interface has been Type Forwarded as of .NET 4.5 from being in PresentationCore.dll to System.dll. I have 2 issues:

1. How can I import this interface so I can use it as a return type of a property I am injecting into a class (don't need help with property injection, just type resolution/importing)?
2. How can I be sure that my resulting assembly will work on .NET 4 clients who don't have .NET 4.5 installed and as such do not have [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) type forwarded to System.dll?

The code is intended to be used in a custom [Fody](http://github.com/Fody/Fody) weaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle it explicitly.

For example finding `Action` which can exist in diff assemblies.

```
var msCoreLibDefinition = assemblyResolver.Resolve("mscorlib");
var msCoreTypes = msCoreLibDefinition.MainModule.Types;
var systemDefinition = assemblyResolver.Resolve("System");
var systemTypes = systemDefinition.MainModule.Types;
var actionDefinition = msCoreTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Action");
if (actionDefinition == null)
{
    actionDefinition = systemTypes.First(x => x.Name == "Action");
}
```